# How to get field values from redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I am unable to get field values in my submit callback. Instead I am receiving an event there. 
Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong

[image: This is what I am getting in my submit callback]

```js
render() {
    const { fields, handleSubmit, submitting, buttonWrapper, btnText } = this.props;
    return (
      <form name="AddEvent" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        {fields.map(field => (
          <div className={field.wrapperClass}>
            <Field
              name={field.name}
              type={field.type || 'text'}
              component={mapComponentClass(field.componentClass)}
              validate={mapValidators(field.validate)}
              props={field.inputProps}
              label={field.label}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
        <div className="form-submit-wrap container">
            <button
              type="submit"
              disabled={submitting}
              className="form-submit"
            >
              {submitting ? 'Submitting' : 'Submit'}
            </button>
          </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
```

Comment: could you please add your redux form code

Comment: Of course you get an event there, it's an event. The form values are in state. See the redux-form docs for how to handle this, e.g., http://redux-form.com/7.0.0/examples/submitValidation/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`handleSubmit` is supposed to be a wrapper of your `onSubmit` function.

Try it like this:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
</form>
```

Now `onSubmit` will receive 1 argument with all the form values.

Not that you asked for it, but as a side note, if you want, you can trigger a submit validation error from inside your `onSubmit` function like:

```
throw ReduxForm.SubmissionError({name: 'There\'s something wrong in the name field'});
```

... as a result of your Ajax call to make `name` invalid.